# How to test liveness failures?

Tags: java, concurrency

In Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, Item 66, he exemplifies a lifeness failure by failing to communicate a variable between threads.

```
// Broken! - How long would you expect this program to run?
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested)
                    i++;
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

He says on his own machine this never terminates, and gives two reasons. I tried this on my own machine, on Oracle JDK 7u75 (newest 7), and it ALWAYS terminates after one second. I also tried starting the runtime with `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` without success. Is there any reason why this is not working as intended (edit: *i.e.* not looping forever)? Is Joshua using another runtime? I have a quad-core ivy bridge.

Answer (score 1):

`stopRequested` is not `volatile`. So, there is no guarantee that the changes made to it by the main thread will be seen by the `backgroundThread`. Changes could be seen, changes might not be seen. There is no guarantee. So (as always), Joshua is right :)

Comment: There may be no guarantee, but I at least expect it to fail, because two threads on a quad-core processor ought to use different cores (L1 and L2 cache are both per-core)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus - :) 4 physical cores = 8 logical cores (HyperThreading). So, ideally yes, 2 threads ought to use different cores.  But each thread will be reading data from its own cache.. So, the main thread will terminate while the background thread waits forever. Why do you expect the boolean value to be written by one thread to be seen by the other?

Comment: I expect it to not be. ('Working as intended' means failure because `volatile` is missing). But it is. And indeed, I noticed I have hyperthreading, which may be the cause.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus - I have a quad core system (8 logical cores). With java8, I am getting the same result as Joshua i.e, *waiting forever* :P